# Registering custom codec (mongo-java-driver-3.7.0-rc0)

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using mongo-java-driver-3.7.0-rc0 and I am struggling for about two days with codec registration. I've tried two approaches (fromProviders and fromCodecs) - none has been working. My current implementation (based on documentation) goes like this:

```
CodecRegistry cr = 
    fromRegistries(com.mongodb.MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
        CodecRegistries.fromProviders(new MongoCacheDocumentCodecProvider()));

MongoClientSettings mongoSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()                                               
                                    .applyConnectionString(connectionString)                                                       
                                    .codecRegistry(cr)
                                    .build();
client = MongoClients.create(mongoSettings);

(...)

MongoCollection<MongoCacheDocument> collection = 
    db.getCollection(dbName, MongoCacheDocument.class);
```

After that, I see in the debugger that it is registered, however When i try e.g. retrieve that object by

```
collection.find() 
OR
collection.find(MongoCacheDocument.class)
```

I get ClassCastException HashMap -> MongoCacheDocument. When I do this for org.bson.Document, everything goes well.
As far as I understand the codec search done by mongo it is done recursively. Why then it is not resolved correctly, whilst the codec is registered (btw. the debugger does not show, that there is any activity in the custom code/codec provider).

Anyone got similar issues? Maybe it is a bug in 3.7.0-rc0, of which I am not aware of?

PS. The reason I use RC is that it supports broader spectrum of POJO codec in automatic mode and want to be as up-to-date as possible, mostly because Mongo API likes to change from time to time :).

EDIT: I've noticed that it returns a MapCodec (FYI: MongoCacheDocument extends org.bson.Document). I see that Document implements Map, however there's no problem in finding codec precisely for the Document.

Comment: Which Codec? And why? What do you need any custom conversion for? You need to state what you are actually doing and why. 9/10 times you're reading an old blog post and it's something already covered by updates in the driver or a different process which you are actually trying to implement. Less story of the problems, and more expansion on what is currently only the very last line in your question.

Comment: I need to implement a wrapping object, consisted of some properties + value (any type). The value needs to be retrieved exactly as it was persisted. There is no way that i could implement codec for each value type (n-types), however Mongo resolves most of the cases with POJO codec, so that's good enough. As for now I was retrieving the wrapping object as document and then using Jackson mapper to reconstruct the object with given class. The thing i want to achieve is to have Mongo resolve it at fetch level (i.e. collection.find()). Is this possible, or is my approach completely wrong?

Comment: You're not understanding is the problem here. We need to "see the codec implementation". We're pretty smart folks here, so we will be able to see what you are doing, what could be wrong and if you even need it at all. Pretty much was why I essentially asked for "less words and more **show**". But all you just gave me there is "more words". Need to see the code to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the above question , You need to implement the AbstractMongoClientConfiguration abstract class for register the custom codec and provides. let me know if you require more information